# Canadian Postal Code - Get Town

Tags: web-scraping

I have a large list of Canadian postal codes and I have been searching around for a way to programatically get the associated city. Anyone know of any good tools for this or have any insight as to how I could go about tackling this?

Comment: define "list"; is it something that maps cities to codes, or codes to cities?

Comment: Mapping codes to cities, such as M2M3W2

Comment: Not really sure why this gets down-voted...it's a legitimate question?

Comment: @JoeyOrlando One of our default close reasons is "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow". That's why you're getting downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Python question, but a data question. Canada Post does not freely publish postal code --> town relationships. [You will have to purchase it from Canada Post](https://www.canadapost.ca/web/en/pages/datalists/default.page?ecid=murl12008556).

Answer (score 1):

I'd look for a web api service.  You can look at [Canada Post Web Services](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/drc/home?execution=e1s1).  The address complete service looks promising.  If it's not too rate-limited, you can just look them up as you go and cache what you already know locally.